# cordova update does not update www/cordova.js

Tags: ios, cordova

After running commands

```
"cordova platform update ios"
```

and

```
"cordova build ios"
```

on MacOS, the file `./platforms/ios/www/cordova.js` was updated but the file `www/cordova.js` was not.

I expected that

```
"platform update"
```

should update `www/cordova.js`, then the

```
"build ios"
```

would update `./platforms/ios/www/cordova.js`.  `./platforms/ios/www/cordova.js` is the correct version.  Files `./platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova.js`, `./platforms/ios/CordovaLib/cordova.js` and `./platforms/ios/build/emulator/iAcquire.app/www/cordova.js` were also updated to the correct version.  Anyone have any idea why this is not working the way I expect?